# How add a list inside a map in kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, hashmap, mutablelist

I need to add some `MutableList<String>` to a map `Map<String, List<String>>`, here is how I tried to initialize it :

```
    private var theSteps: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    private var optionsList: Map<String, List<String>> = mapOf()
```

Then I add data to the `MutableList this way :

```
        theSteps.add("one")
        theSteps.add("two")
        theSteps.add("three")
```

everything works fine untill i try to add to the `Map`:

`optionsList.add("list_1" to theSteps)`

It just gives me the error `Unresolved reference add` and I can't find clear documentation about how to add items to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`optionsList` must be a `MutableMap` to add anything, just like you have a `MutableList`; or you can use

```
theSteps += "list_1" to theSteps
```

to create a *new* map with the added pair and update `theSteps` variable. This calls the [`plus` extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html):

> Creates a new read-only map by replacing or adding an entry to this map from a given key-value pair.

(search for the above to get to the correct overload)

Answer (score 2):

You can't add to your map because `mapOf` is creating a [read-only map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html)

> ```
> fun <K, V> mapOf(): Map<K, V>
> ```
>
> Returns an empty read-only map.

You probably want to create a [MutableMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/index.html#kotlin.collections.MutableMap) (or similar)

```
private var optionsList: Map<String, List<String>> = mutableMapOf()
```

You can then use plus method:

```
optionsList = optionsList.plus("list_1" to theSteps)
```

Or see [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464679/how-to-work-with-maps-in-kotlin) as @voddan:

> ```
> val nameTable = mutableMapOf<String, Person>()    
> fun main (args: Array<String>) {
>     nameTable["person1"] = example
> ```